# Geocoder returns location in another language even when set to english

Tags: android, google-geocoder

I am using the following code and I have tried most of the answers on stack-overflow, but it still returns the location in different languages for some users.

**What Happens:**
For some users even if I set the default language to English, it returns the location in Nepali. I did try myself by changing my phone's language to Nepali, but it's returning in English.

My Code: 
**on Create Fragment**

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH); 
LocationRetreive(locationLatitude, locationLongitude);
```

**Method**

```
    private void LocationRetreive(Double locationLatitude, Double locationLongitude) {
    try {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(locationLatitude, locationLongitude, 1);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            string_city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            string_state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            string_country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
            string_location = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);


            if (string_country == null) {
                if (string_state != null) {
                    string_country = string_state;
                } else if (string_city != null) {
                    string_country = string_city;
                } else {
                    string_country = "null";
                }
            }
            if (string_city == null) {
                if (string_state != null) {
                    string_city = string_state;
                } else {
                    string_city = string_country;
                }
            }
            if (string_state == null) {
                if (string_city != null) {
                    string_state = string_city;
                } else {
                    string_state = string_country;
                }
            }
            if (string_location == null) {
                string_location = "Null";
            }


        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60018046/geocoder-returns-location-in-another-language-even-when-set-to-english)

Comment: Sounds like this feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63829150

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "GB"));  
Locale new_locale = Locale.getDefault();
```

instead.